# How to enable TLSv1.3 in Centos with Apache2

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl

I am using CentOS 5 with Apache2.

Into an additional config file:

```
/etc/apache2/conf/extra/ssl.conf
```

I have put these lines:

```
SSLHonorCipherOrder On 
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 
SSLCipherSuite TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

I still can't enable TLSv1.3. The error says when restarting the service

> ```
> Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 113 of /etc/apache2/conf/extra/ssl.conf: 
> SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.3'
> ```

---

System: CentOS 5.11 (Final).

OpenSSL: 1.1.1a 20 Nov 2018.

Comment: Can you provide the version details for your OS, Apache & OpenSSL?

Comment: Did you show us line 113? I don't see a TLSv1.3 entry...?

Comment: Centos 5 is too old to support that, I think. What have you installed?

Comment: hi, my OS is CentOS release 5.11 (Final). Openssl is OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018

Comment: @JeffSchaller .. the error is when i put the 
**SSLProtocol TLSv1.3**

Comment: It's confusing when your demonstrated config file lines don't contain TLSv1.3 ... IMHO you should update the question to demonstrate the error *and* the configuration that's failing.

Comment: @JeffSchaller.. sorry for confusion.
I should edit that.. thanks

Comment: Is there any configuration that  I should add (or maybe I miss out) in my ssl.conf?  TSL1.3 is still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you would need the very latest Apache version in order for the following to work:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.3 +TLSv1.2
```

This is simpler than disabling all of the other obsolete protocols.

---

And then you need to define pre-TLSv1.3 cipher suites separately. Like so:

```
SSLCipherSuite    TLSv1.3   TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
SSLCipherSuite    SSL       ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

Comment: thanks for your respond.
but after I added the suggested lines, got error:

_Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 108 of /etc/apache2/conf/extra/ssl.conf:
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.3'
                                                           [FAILED]_

can you help me out of this. I  appreciates much.

Comment: @jonathan.rtz Post your openssl version.

Comment: here it is
my OS is CentOS release 5.11 (Final). Openssl is OpenSSL 1.1.1a 20 Nov 2018

Comment: ok. thank you! i will wait. thanks again.

Comment: Is there any configuration that I should add or maybe I miss out in my ssl.conf? TSL1.3 is still disabled.